# Why did Mîm not leave the sack with Túrin and leave?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, children-of-hurin

In *The Children of Húrin*, after Mîm is captured by Túrin and his outlaws, he promises to lead them to his house, in ransom for his life.

At first, he attempts to leave them for the night, and promises to return by day. They are unwilling to let him leave without some safety, such as his sack. Then, on the one hand, he claims that, if he planned to run away, his old sack would not have dissuaded him; but, on the other hand, he is nonetheless not willing to leave it behind, and stays with them for the night. It is implied that he is lying, and that there is something more valuable in the sack than they know.

> 'Judge my home when you  see it. But you will need light on your way,
> you stumbling Men. I will return in good time  and lead you.' Then he
> rose and picked up his sack.
>
> 'No, no!' said Androg. 'You will not allow this, surely, captain? You
> would never see the  old rascal again.'
>
> 'It is growing dark,' said Turin. 'Let him leave us some pledge. Shall
> we keep your sack  and its load, Mim?'
>
> But at this the Dwarf fell on his knees again in great trouble. 'If
> Mim did not mean to  return, he would not return for an old sack of
> roots,' he said. 'I will come back. Let me  go!'
>
> 'I will not,' said Turin. 'If you will not part with your sack, you
> must stay with it. A night  under the leaves will make you pity us in
> your turn, maybe.' But he marked, and others  also, that Mim set more store by the sack and his load than it seemed worth to the eye.

Later, Mîm supposedly explains his behavior.

> That day they rested, and cleaned their arms and mended their gear;
> for they had food to  last a day or two yet, and Mim added to what
> they had.
>
> Three great cooking-pots he lent to them, and firing; and he brought
> out a sack. 'Rubbish,'  he said. 'Not worth the stealing. Only wild
> roots.'
>
> But when they were washed the roots proved white and fleshy with their
> skins, and when  boiled they were good to eat, somewhat like bread;
> and the outlaws were glad of them,  for they had long lacked bread
> save when they could steal it. 'Wild Elves know them not;  Grey-elves
> have not found them; the proud ones from over the Sea are too proud to
> delve,' said Mim.
>
> 'What is their name?' said Turin.
>
> Mim looked at him sidelong. 'They have no name, save in the
> dwarf-tongue, which we do  not teach,' he said. 'And we do not teach
> Men to find them, for Men are greedy and  thriftless, and would not
> spare till all the plants had perished; whereas now they pass  them by
> as they go blundering in the wild. No more will you learn of me; but
> you may  have enough of my bounty, as long as you speak fair and do
> not spy or steal.' Then again  he laughed in his throat. 'They are of
> great worth,' he said. 'More than gold in the hungry  winter, for they
> may be hoarded like the nuts of a squirrel, and already we were
> building  our store from the first that are ripe. But you are fools,
> if you think that I would not be  parted from one small load even for
> the saving of my life.'
>
> 'I hear you,' said Ulrad, who had looked in the sack when Mim was
> taken.
>
> 'Yet you would not be parted, and your words only make me wonder the
> more.'
>
> Mim turned and looked at him darkly. 'You are one of the fools that
> spring would not  mourn if you perished in winter,' he said to him. 'I
> had spoken my word, and so must  have returned, willing or not, with
> sack or without, let a lawless and faithless man think  what he will!
> But I love not to be parted from my own by force of the wicked, be it
> no  more than a shoe-thong. Do I not remember that your hands were
> among those that put  bonds upon me, and so held me that I did not
> speak again with my son? Ever when I deal  out the earth-bread from my
> store you will be counted out, and if you eat it, you shall eat  by
> the bounty of your fellows, not of me.'
>
> Then Mim went away; but Ulrad, who had quailed under his anger, spoke
> to his back:  'High words! Nonetheless the old rogue had other things
> in his sack, of like shape but  harder and heavier. Maybe there are
> other things beside earth-bread in the wild which  Elves have not
> found and Men must not know!'

This whole story just seems very strange to me.

1. If Mîm was lying when he said he'd come back after the night, and wanted to escape, then why not leave the sack behind, and run away? As valuable as these roots may be, they're hardly worth the ransom of his house, and it seems he knows how to find many more.
2. If Mîm wasn't lying, and really did plan to come back after the night, then why not leave the sack behind as assurance, and come back? Again, it seems impossible to me he'd be unwilling to part with it, even for a night, if all there's in it is just some roots. He says: "I love not to be parted from my own by force of the wicked, be it no more than a shoe-thong." But I find it difficult to believe that the very idea of of being parted with his sorry sack (or of leaving assurance behind him) was so offensive to his pride that he preferred to stay with them for the night - not when the price was not seeing his dying son, and not when the result of this proud insistence was that they'd simply think he's unwilling to part with his sack because it's very valuable.

No matter how you slice it, it seems clear that Ulrad was right. There was more to this sack then Mîm admitted. But what was it? Why was he not willing to part with it?

Unless I missed something, this is not explained in the rest of the book, and the sack is not even mentioned in *The Silmarillion*. Is it explained anywhere at all?

(Of course, it is a reasonable guess that there was jewellery in the sack, or something very expensive. But I thought that perhaps there is more that can be said on this subject).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read somewhere (maybe *Children of Hurin*) that Mim stole treasure from Nargothrond after it was sacked by the dragon (Glaurung?) and hid it in his hill

Comment: @HahemLovesYou I doubt this was in the Children of Húrin tbh. Do you think it was in his sack then? Is there any chance you read this in the History of Middle-Earth?

Comment: not fully. I read Silmarillion and The Great Tales.

Comment: nvm I checked Tolkien Gateway, he only stole treasure from Nargothrond later